# Large volume at /mnt on AWS instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I know this is probably a somewhat 'dumb' question :)

I have an AWS (small) instance and I just noticed that there is a ~150gb volume attached at /mnt, is this normal?

It kinda freaked me out, I was thinking maybe someone was trying to capture whatever I mount in /mnt, there is the entry in my fstab too (and I found that others have this by googling)... the entry is as follows

```
/dev/xvdb   /mnt    auto    defaults,nobootwait,comment=cloudconfig 0   2
```

I don't have any volumes this large in my AWS volumes section though. I was just trying to understand this and be sure that someone is not trying to 'get in'... as there are many attempts daily.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's called ephemeral/instance storage (see http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/). Basically, it's temporary storage space which is cleared on instance stop/termination. Suitable for temporary storage.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it was such but couldn't confirm... and didn't panic but wanted to know. I did all my development on the micro instance and just went production recently.

Comment: Um, no, it exists still after reboot. If you terminate the instance or the instance dies on its own, that disk storage is lost, so back it up to S3.

Comment: Ephemeral storage survives reboot, but is cleared on stop/start, terminate, and instance failure.  I explain more differences between reboot and stop/start here: http://alestic.com/2011/09/ec2-reboot-stop-start